# How can I concatenate DataFrame in loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, concatenation

I have a for loop with n iterations.
Every itineration results in a DataFrame (6, 1). Then after the last itineration, I get n *times* (6, 1) DataFrames. I want to get ONE DataFrame with (6, n).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np # for calculating standard deviation and mean
import scipy.stats as sp # for calculating standard error
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qtagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import time
import easygui as eg
import os
import glob

path = r'F:\Phyton\wt_depolarizations/*.txt'
entries = glob.glob(path)
l=len(entries)


for number in range(l):
        depol=pd.read_csv(entries[number])
        filename=os.path.basename(entries[number]).split('.')[0]
        depol_numpy=depol.to_numpy()
        time=np.arange(0, 300, (1/20000))
        plt.plot(time,depol_numpy)
        plt.show(block=False)
        
        eg.msgbox(msg='Zoom in', title='title')
        
        x = plt.ginput(2)
        
        x=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['y-index','x-index'])
       
        
     
        indexbsl=round(x.iloc[0,0],0)
        indexwo=round(x.iloc[1,0],0)
        indexbsl=indexbsl.astype(int)
        indexwo=indexwo.astype(int)
        bsl=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[0:indexbsl,0])
        bsl.columns = ['bsl points']
        wo=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[indexwo:-1,0])
        wo.columns = ['wo points']
      
        points=pd.concat([bsl, wo])
        mean=points.mean()
        mean.index=['bsl mean','wo mean']
        std=points.std()
        std.index=['bsl std','wo std']
        coef_var_bsl=pd.Series(std[0]/mean[0])
        coef_var_bsl.index=['bsl coef var']
        coef_var_wo=pd.Series(std[1]/mean[1])
        coef_var_wo.index=['wo coef var']
    
       
        parameters=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([mean, std, coef_var_bsl, coef_var_wo])
                                , columns = [filename])
        plt.plot(points)
        parameters.to_excel("% s.xlsx" % filename)
        
        plt.close()
```

The variable parameter collects in a DataFrame all the data I want to export in an excel file. I want to get one excel file with all the parameters instead of multiple n excel files.

---EDIT---
This code almost fulfils my needs @chitown88

```
df_list = [] # <-- initilize a list to store the dataframes
for number in range(l):
        depol=pd.read_csv(entries[number])
        filename=os.path.basename(entries[number]).split('.')[0]
        depol_numpy=depol.to_numpy()
        time=np.arange(0, 300, (1/20000))
        plt.plot(time,depol_numpy)
        plt.show(block=False)
        
        eg.msgbox(msg='Zoom in', title='title')
        
        x = plt.ginput(2)
        
        x=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['y-index','x-index'])
       
        
     
        indexbsl=round(x.iloc[0,0],0)
        indexwo=round(x.iloc[1,0],0)
        indexbsl=indexbsl.astype(int)
        indexwo=indexwo.astype(int)
        bsl=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[0:indexbsl,0])
        bsl.columns = ['bsl points']
        wo=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[indexwo:-1,0])
        wo.columns = ['wo points']
      
        points=pd.concat([bsl, wo])
        mean=points.mean()
        mean.index=['bsl mean','wo mean']
        std=points.std()
        std.index=['bsl std','wo std']
        coef_var_bsl=pd.Series(std[0]/mean[0])
        coef_var_bsl.index=['bsl coef var']
        coef_var_wo=pd.Series(std[1]/mean[1])
        coef_var_wo.index=['wo coef var']
    
       # parameters=pd.concat([mean, std, coef_var_bsl, coef_var_wo])
        parameters=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([mean, std, coef_var_bsl, coef_var_wo])
                                , columns = [filename])
        df_list.append(parameters) # <-- put each dataframe into that list
        #parameters.to_excel("% s.xlsx" % filename)
        
        plt.close()


final_df = pd.concat(df_list)     # <-- combine all the parameters dataframes into 1 dataframe and write to file     
final_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

However, this is the aspect of the file
[weird distribution of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJn0e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just do what you are already doing with concat in your loop, just instead of writing the excel to file in each iteration, out the datafame into a list, concat that after the loop finishes, then write to file.

So something like:

```
df_list = [] # <-- initilize a list to store the dataframes
for number in range(l):
        depol=pd.read_csv(entries[number])
        filename=os.path.basename(entries[number]).split('.')[0]
        depol_numpy=depol.to_numpy()
        time=np.arange(0, 300, (1/20000))
        plt.plot(time,depol_numpy)
        plt.show(block=False)
        
        eg.msgbox(msg='Zoom in', title='title')
        
        x = plt.ginput(2)
        
        x=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['y-index','x-index'])
       
        
     
        indexbsl=round(x.iloc[0,0],0)
        indexwo=round(x.iloc[1,0],0)
        indexbsl=indexbsl.astype(int)
        indexwo=indexwo.astype(int)
        bsl=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[0:indexbsl,0])
        bsl.columns = ['bsl points']
        wo=pd.DataFrame(depol.iloc[indexwo:-1,0])
        wo.columns = ['wo points']
      
        points=pd.concat([bsl, wo])
        mean=points.mean()
        mean.index=['bsl mean','wo mean']
        std=points.std()
        std.index=['bsl std','wo std']
        coef_var_bsl=pd.Series(std[0]/mean[0])
        coef_var_bsl.index=['bsl coef var']
        coef_var_wo=pd.Series(std[1]/mean[1])
        coef_var_wo.index=['wo coef var']
    
       
        parameters=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([mean, std, coef_var_bsl, coef_var_wo])
                                , columns = [filename])
        df_list.append(parameters) # <-- put each dataframe into that list
        
        plt.plot(points)
        
        
        plt.close()

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)     # <-- combine all the parameters dataframes into 1 dataframe and write to file     
final_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Almost!! See the pic attached to my first comment. Nevertheless, it works! But it looks weird: data is written in a step-like fashion.

Comment: I used df.assign and now looks exactly as I want. However, thanks for saw me the correct path!

Comment: ya assign way to go. I was just basing it off the code you provided